# Controller Not Generate To Modules Directory YII2 via Gii

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

i am using YII 2.0.4 and i made one module via gii.

module name is `service` as i want to make web service by using this module.

but when i tried to make `controller` in this `service` module module it will not work its giving error like below image

[image: Yii2 gii issue while controller generating]

i also read this post https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4413

but i don't understand what i need do. please help me to generate controller via `gii`.

Comment: do you have *controllers* directory in your *modules/service* directory ?

Comment: Thanks @Tony when i generate module on that time i didn't get controllers directory i made it manually. its worked now thanks

Comment: i think controller directory need to auto generate if not exists in module while i am generating any controller via gii.